# How can I put data frame data into bins

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
12.1 12.5 12.6 12.7 12.8 13.0 13.2 13.2 13.2 13.3 13.3 13.3 
13.4 13.4 13.5 13.5 13.7 13.7 13.7 13.8 13.9 14.1 14.1 14.2 
14.3 14.3 14.3 14.4 14.4 14.5 14.6 14.6 14.6 14.8 14.8 14.9 
14.9 14.9 15.2 15.2 15.3 15.3 15.5 15.6 15.6 15.7 15.8 15.9 
16.1 16.1 16.3 16.4 16.4 16.5 16.7 16.9 17.0
```

and I'd like to put it into these bins:

```
12.1 12.5 12.6 12.7 12.8 13.0 13.2 13.3 13.4 13.5 13.7 13.8 
13.9 14.1 14.2 14.3 14.4 14.5 14.6 14.8 14.9 15.2 15.3 15.5 
15.6 15.7 15.8 15.9 16.1 16.3 16.4 16.5 16.7 16.9 17.0
```

So for example, the 13.2 and 13.3 bins would have 3 items, etc.

I should mention that the dataset has other columns I want to follow this numeric data into the bins.

I'm new to R and trying to figure out binning.

Here is code to setup my data, and the unique values:

```
test <- function() {
    data <- c(12.1,12.5,12.6,12.7,12.8,13.0,13.2,13.2,13.2,13.3,13.3,13.3,
13.4,13.4,13.5,13.5,13.7,13.7,13.7,13.8,13.9,14.1,14.1,14.2,
14.3,14.3,14.3,14.4,14.4,14.5,14.6,14.6,14.6,14.8,14.8,14.9,
14.9,14.9,15.2,15.2,15.3,15.3,15.5,15.6,15.6,15.7,15.8,15.9,
16.1,16.1,16.3,16.4,16.4,16.5,16.7,16.9,17.0)

    unique_data = unique(data)

    print(unique_data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "x" is your input vector and "y" is your vector of breaks points, you should just use `cut`:

```
cut(x, c(-Inf, y, Inf))
```

Here's an example of what the bin counts look like:

```
table(cut(x, c(-Inf, y, Inf)))
# 
# (-Inf,12.1] (12.1,12.5] (12.5,12.6] (12.6,12.7] (12.7,12.8]   (12.8,13] 
#           1           1           1           1           1           1 
#   (13,13.2] (13.2,13.3] (13.3,13.4] (13.4,13.5] (13.5,13.7] (13.7,13.8] 
#           3           3           2           2           3           1 
# (13.8,13.9] (13.9,14.1] (14.1,14.2] (14.2,14.3] (14.3,14.4] (14.4,14.5] 
#           1           2           1           3           2           1 
# (14.5,14.6] (14.6,14.8] (14.8,14.9] (14.9,15.2] (15.2,15.3] (15.3,15.5] 
#           3           2           3           2           2           1 
# (15.5,15.6] (15.6,15.7] (15.7,15.8] (15.8,15.9] (15.9,16.1] (16.1,16.3] 
#           2           1           1           1           2           1 
# (16.3,16.4] (16.4,16.5] (16.5,16.7] (16.7,16.9]   (16.9,17]   (17, Inf] 
#           2           1           1           1           1           0
```

You may have to tweak some of the arguments to get the values to fall in the bins you expect them to, but `cut` is generally the function for this, along with `findInterval` as a close relative.

Comment: The data is actually a two column data frame. I need to bin the rows of the data frame based on the unique values of the 2nd column, but in the result, I still need the data frame two columns of data intact. Binning the 2nd column just helps me identify which rows have the same 2nd column value.

Comment: @GregLafrance, please try to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), preferably one that is also (1) small, and (2) that includes an example of your desired output.

Comment: Added a function to create the data and get unique values. Now I need to find out how to bin the data by the unique values.

Comment: @GregLafrance, what I meant was a small example that actually show what your `data.frame` might look like (you mention you have a two-column `data.frame` but that you want to do this exercise *by row* (?).

Answer (score 0):

The [dplyr package](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) contains some handy tools for doing this sort of thing.

Assuming you have a data frame `df` where the values you've mentioned are in a column `value`, you can bin and count unique values using syntax like:

```
binned = df %.% group_by(value) %.% summarise(count=n())
```

`binned` will have columns `value` and `count`.

`summarise` lets you add other summary statistics. If you wanted to add the mean of some column `other_value`, you could do that like:

```
binned = df %.% group_by(value) %.% summarise(count=n(), mean_other_val=mean(other_val))
```

Now, `binned` will have columns `value`, `count`, and `mean_other_val`.